# Extension Library for lotus notes 853

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, xpages-extlib

which Extension Library IBM  support for Lotus Notes 853?
currently we use the extLib version: 8.5.3.20111208-0717, which we install over the 8.5.3 Upgrade Pack 1. But I miss in this version the restservice xe:customrestservice e.g.

So my question is, can I download every extlib version for 8.5.3 from openntf and install that, without lost my ibm support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last release for 8.5.3 is [853.20130315-0724](http://extlib.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPages%20Extension%20Library/releases/56832E9BD6A0615186257B4300349C59) from Apr 4, 2013.

Comment: thank you Knut, but is this release also support from ibm. my it manager allow online supported releases in our environment

Comment: As far as I know only Extlib UP1 is officially supported by IBM.

Comment: It depends what support your manager expects from IBM. It may be officially supported, but you're unlikely to get fixes for UP1 released in a fix pack for 8.5.3. In order to get a supported version with the fix, IBM will probably expect you to upgrade to the next fix pack.
Defects can be raised against it and IBM may publish fixes. It's also open source for a reason - anyone can fix issues for you and I have done that in the past for a customer. If you want support from another company with a chance of getting a fix in a timely fashion, speak to an IBM Business Partner.

Comment: @KnutHerrmann, I would like to ask, is there any extension library class for java and is it posible to call or show dialogbox using java?

Comment: @simon: An extension for Java is OpenNTF Domino API http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/OpenNTF%20Domino%20API. You can use it as of Notes Domino version 9. It doesn't provide UI functions like dialog boxes though. For this you'd use the Extlib.